# Creating multiple dictionaries from CSV - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

### Issue

I'm wanting to create multiple dictionaries on the basis that they all have a unique identifier that is on the first row of a CSV file

I want to call 2911['ipadd'] to return the relevant code on the second line of the CSV file, but I'm stumped.

I've found this which seems close enough to what I want to achieve [Creating multiple nested dictionaries from .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519518/creating-multiple-nested-dictionaries-from-txt-file)

However people are recommending stuff that doesn't apply to my solution so it is hit and miss.

### Code

```
mylist = []

with open('file.csv','r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for row in reader:
      mylist.append({'name': row[0], 'ipadd': row[1], 'mac': row[2], 'interfaces': row[3:]})

for line in mylist:
   print(line['ipadd'])
```

I tried uniquely identifiying a variable by the first row and then using that to append the information to but of course variables don't have the 'append' function.

### CSV information

2811,1.1.1.1,AA:BB:CC:DD:EE, Fa0/0,Fa0/1,Fa1/0,Fa1/1

2911,2.2.2.2,BB:CC:DD:EE:FF, S0/0/0,S0/0/1,S0/1/0,S0/1/1

Comment: Please post a sample of your file and your desired output from that sample

Comment: @Ajax1234 my mistake I'll add that to the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a work around; I ended up creating an object

```
class router:
   name = ''
   ipadd = ''
   mac = ''
   interfaces = []
   def __init__(self, name, ipadd, mac, interfaces):
      self.name = name
      self.ipadd = ipadd
      self.mac = mac
      self.interfaces = interfaces

with open('file.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    item = row[0]
    newitem = item.split('\t')
    mylist.append(router(newitem[0], newitem[1], newitem[2], newitem[3:]))
```

Comment: @Ajax1234 - Is this something you think is suitable for the answer? 2 lines of code after the for loop is a little inelegant but it gets the job done

Comment: Feel free to mark this solution as answered if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv
headers = ['name', 'ipadd', 'mac', 'interfaces']
new_data = [{a:b for a, b in zip(headers, i[:3]+[i[3:]])} for i in csv.reader(open('file.csv'))]
```

Comment: The code works and looks nice, however it only displays elegantly when specifying

for line in new_data:

      print(line['name'])

Comment: @DannyWatson what would you like as an alternative?

Comment: I think I may have to implement an object to achieve my goal, I'm going to have to figure out how to dynamically create objects based on the value in the first row of each column in the csv

Comment: @DannyWatson what specifically do you wish to do with the values in the first row of each column?

Comment: It is in the original post "I want to call 2911['ipadd'] to return the relevant code on the second line of the CSV file, but I'm stumped."

Comment: can you review my proposed resolution?